# Change markup for just 2nd list element in custom Walker menu

Tags: menus, navigation, walker

I have been struggling a bit with this idea. The thing I want to achieve is that all elements are regular dropdown but the second one is a megamenu styled item.

And for that I have prepared markup but and want it to be applied only to 2nd element in the list. I am stuck a bit.

This is something what I want [link](https://codepen.io/umaknow-emmanuel/pen/XVXyXX)

```
<?php

class Walker_Nav_Primary extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    /**
     * What the class handles.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @var string
     *
     * @see Walker::$tree_type
     */
    public $tree_type = array( 'post_type', 'taxonomy', 'custom' );

    /**
     * Database fields to use.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @todo Decouple this.
     * @var array
     *
     * @see Walker::$db_fields
     */
    public $db_fields = array(
        'parent' => 'menu_item_parent',
        'id'     => 'db_id',
    );

    /**
     * Starts the list before the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::start_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */

    public function display_element( $element, &$children_elements, $max_depth, $depth = 0, $args, &$output ) {


        // if it is a root element and the menu is not flat, add 'has-dropdown' class 
        // from https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L140
        $element->has_children = ! empty( $children_elements[ $element->ID ] );
        $element->classes[] = ( $element->has_children && 1 !== $max_depth && $element == 1 ) ? 'dropdown-fullwidth-container' : '';

        // call parent method
        parent::display_element( $element, $children_elements, $max_depth, $depth, $args, $output );
     }

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

        // Default class.
        $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
         *
         * @since 4.8.0
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";

    }

    /**
     * Ends the list of after the elements are added.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_lvl()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent  = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
        $output .= "$indent</ul>{$n}";

    }

    /**
     * Starts the element output.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     * @since 4.4.0 The {@see 'nav_menu_item_args'} filter was added.
     *
     * @see Walker::start_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Menu item data object.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     * @param int      $id     Current item ID.
     */
    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( $t, $depth ) : '';

        $classes   = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'mmenu-expand-dropdown';

        /**
         * Filters the arguments for a single nav menu item.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $args = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_args', $args, $item, $depth );

        /**
         * Filters the CSS classes applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string[] $classes Array of the CSS classes that are applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args, $depth ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the ID applied to a menu item's list item element.
         *
         * @since 3.0.1
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param string   $menu_id The ID that is applied to the menu item's `<li>` element.
         * @param WP_Post  $item    The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args    An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-' . $item->ID, $item, $args, $depth );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        if($depth == 0) {

            $output .= $indent . '<li' . $class_names . '>';

        }   else {

            $output .= $indent . '<li>';

        }

        $atts                 = array();
        $atts['title']        = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? $item->attr_title : '';
        $atts['target']       = ! empty( $item->target ) ? $item->target : '';
        $atts['rel']          = ! empty( $item->xfn ) ? $item->xfn : '';
        $atts['href']         = ! empty( $item->url ) ? $item->url : '';
        $atts['aria-current'] = $item->current ? 'page' : '';

        /**
         * Filters the HTML attributes applied to a menu item's anchor element.
         *
         * @since 3.6.0
         * @since 4.1.0 The `$depth` parameter was added.
         *
         * @param array $atts {
         *     The HTML attributes applied to the menu item's `<a>` element, empty strings are ignored.
         *
         *     @type string $title        Title attribute.
         *     @type string $target       Target attribute.
         *     @type string $rel          The rel attribute.
         *     @type string $href         The href attribute.
         *     @type string $aria_current The aria-current attribute.
         * }
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $atts = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', $atts, $item, $args, $depth );

        $attributes = '';
        foreach ( $atts as $attr => $value ) {
            if ( ! empty( $value ) ) {
                $value       = ( 'href' === $attr ) ? esc_url( $value ) : esc_attr( $value );
                $attributes .= ' ' . $attr . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID );

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's title.
         *
         * @since 4.4.0
         *
         * @param string   $title The menu item's title.
         * @param WP_Post  $item  The current menu item.
         * @param stdClass $args  An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         * @param int      $depth Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         */
        $title = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_title', $title, $item, $args, $depth );

        $item_output  = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . $title . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        /**
         * Filters a menu item's starting output.
         *
         * The menu item's starting output only includes `$args->before`, the opening `<a>`,
         * the menu item's title, the closing `</a>`, and `$args->after`. Currently, there is
         * no filter for modifying the opening and closing `<li>` for a menu item.
         *
         * @since 3.0.0
         *
         * @param string   $item_output The menu item's starting HTML output.
         * @param WP_Post  $item        Menu item data object.
         * @param int      $depth       Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
         * @param stdClass $args        An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
         */
        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }

    /**
     * Ends the element output, if needed.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @see Walker::end_el()
     *
     * @param string   $output Used to append additional content (passed by reference).
     * @param WP_Post  $item   Page data object. Not used.
     * @param int      $depth  Depth of page. Not Used.
     * @param stdClass $args   An object of wp_nav_menu() arguments.
     */
    public function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
        if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
            $t = '';
            $n = '';
        } else {
            $t = "\t";
            $n = "\n";
        }
        $output .= "</li>{$n}";
    }
}
```

Comment: There are plugins for mega menu functionality that work pretty well (Max Mega Menu comes to mind for one), If you want to do this yourself then maybe add a class to the menu item in the admin and then style accordingly.  If you need to change the markup on that item you could check for that class in your walker and build the markup from there.

Comment: Yes, I want to skip plugin and try to code it. I am using custom Walker but having hard time with targeting the 2nd item in root lvl. Any suggestions maybe? Do I use the `display_elements()` function?

Comment: I think that trying to do the 2nd element specifically is a bad idea, what if the menu layout changes and suddenly the menu item you want to be a mega menu is in a different spot? That's why I think adding a class to the menu item in the admin and using that class as your marker to tell if you're on the right item would be a better idea.

Comment: Can you please share your custom walker code?

Comment: I have added the code. I have reused code from `wp-includes` and trying to relize at the moment how to use the $item from `$start_el` inside `start_lvl`.